# how to delete search index in GAE Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

I use Google App Engine Search API, i dont know what is the name of the feature in image below, i want to delete the "customerindex" and "customers"

[image]

maybe the right question is "how to delete the search index?"

Answer (score 3):

On production you can delete the documents within a index but index will still be visible

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Deleting_documents_from_an_index

If you want to delete the index from development server, just restart it.

Comment: after i restart it, yes it deleted, but, after i tried to access and re-add "customerindex" the "customers" appeared again... :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a method available to just delete the search index as is in the Production environment.

You could programmatically look at deleting the documents from the search index (a batch call also exists).

A couple of other SO posts related to this are given here:

- [Delete Indexed Full-Text Search in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365184/delete-indexed-full-text-search-in-google-app-engine)
- [How to delete or reset a search index in Appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388251/how-to-delete-or-reset-a-search-index-in-appengine)